# Probability of two points to be in range

Tags: probability

Let there be two cubes $C_1$ and $C_2$, which are defined via their respective left-front-lower corner $A_1$ and $A_2$ and their right-back-upper corner $B_1$ and $B_2$. The cubes live in 3D Euclidean space and do not overlap.

Now we randomly pick two points: $P_1$ from $C_1$ and $P_2$ from $C_2$.

**The Question:** How do I calculate the probability that the distance between these points is at most $r$? Or in short: Determine $P[|P_2 - P_1| \le r]$

I assume it somehow works via the PDFs of $P_1$ and $P_2$ but I'm not sure how to bring 3D into the approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean by random, a uniform distribution of of each coordinate.
$$
\vec{ P_{1}}\sim Unif(A_1,A_2)\sim\frac{1}{(A_2-A_1)^3}
I_{(A_1,A_2)}(\vec{p_1})
$$
$$
\vec{ P_{2}}\sim Unif(B_1,B_2)\sim\frac{1}{(B_2-B_1)^3}
I_{(B_1,B_2)}(\vec{p_2})
$$
We approach this problem by finding the joint PDF for each coordinate of each point. Since they are independent, the joint PDF is the product of pdfs
$$
f(\vec{p_1},\vec{p_2})=\frac{1}{(A_2-A_1)^3}\frac{1}{(B_2-B_1)^3}I_{(C_1)}(\vec{p_1})I_{(C_2)}(\vec{p_2})
$$
From here to find P[|P2−P1|≤r], we use the property
$$
E[I_Θ]=P[Θ]
$$
to find
$$
 P[|\vec{P_2}−\vec{P_1}|≤r]=E[I_{(0,r)}(|\vec{P_2}−\vec{P_1}|)]$$
$$
=\int_{A_1}^{A_2}\int_{A_1}^{A_2}\int_{A_1}^{A_2}\int_{B_1}^{B_2}\int_{B_1}^{B_2}\int_{B_1}^{B_2}\frac{1}{(A_2-A_1)^3}\frac{1}{(B_2-B_1)^3}I_{(0,r)}(\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2+(z_2-z_1)^2})dx_2dy_2dz_2dx_1dy_1dz_1
$$

Comment: $$I_Θ(x)$$ being the indicator function which is 1 when x is in set Θ and 0 otherwise.

Comment: Also if you wanted to find a formula, you'd have to do a change of bases involving v1=|P2−P1|  and calculate a 6D jacobian, and then figure out the the boundry involving a 6D super mega hyper cube and the distance.